# Disingenuity and intellectual dishonesty

Tags: synonyms

In the midst of the current American political drama, unfolding around the impeachment inquiry into President Donald Trump, the phrase "intellectual dishonesty" has been thrown around by pundits on both sides of the isle to describe the arguments of their opponents on the other.

Disingenuity is described roughly as a being "not straightforward or candid; insincere or calculating". This seems to perfectly mesh with the concept of intellectual dishonesty, as one's sincerity and candidness are arguably direct products of one's application of their intellect to their integrity.

However, the Oxford dictionary also caveats "disingenuous" as arguing in bad faith "typically by pretending that one knows less about something than one really does." One could make the argument that being intellectually dishonest is inherently characterized by feigned ignorance of damning aspects of a counter position.

So my question is if disingenuousness and intellectual dishonesty are reasonable synonyms.

Comment: According to the _American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language_, fifth edition (2010), the normal noun form of _disingenuous_ is _disingenuousness_, not _disingenuity_. _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ (2003) agrees. And certainly _ingenuousness_ and _ingenuity_ are not the same thing. Is there some reason you are particularly interested in the word _disingenuity_ in preference to the word _disingenuousness_?

Comment: I suppose not, besides the fact that disengenuousness took a bus load of vowels hostage, drove them behind the abandoned power plant, and arranged their corpses in a macabre pattern after murdering them cruelly. Also: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disingenuity

Comment: Issues of suffixes aside, the two are rough synonyms but carry some different implications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

The two expressions are clearly kindred spirits.  But there is. subtle difference that is hard to pin down.  It is a matter of tone as much as semantic extension.

Start with the root word: ingenuous (which the spell-check is convinced should be ingenious!).  Merriam Webster defines it thus:

> showing innocent or childlike simplicity or candidness <*sic*, rather than *candour*.

The French speak of an *ingenu*:  an innocent or simpleton.  So its opposite, ***dis***ingenuous is the negation or absence of that quality.  More than that, though, it is a **false** simulation of innocence, ignorance or *naiveté*.

In that sense, it is a cousin of something attributed to Socrates:  ‘*ειρωνεία*’, often translated into the cognate English, *irony*, in the context of his repeated claim to be ignorant or baffled, while demolishing the opinions of his interlocutors.  Whether Socrates was being presented to us by Plato or Xenophon as disingenuous, is uncertain, but in Plato, at least, Socrates’ victims are calling him disingenuous.  What is certain is that he was not being accused of **intellectual dishonesty**.

In U.K. political campaigns of the 1980s and ‘90s, A habit by the government party grew up, in which the spokesperson would respond to challenges that if the party won it would raise these taxes or cut those social benefits, in the following *disingenuous* way:

> We have no plans to do that.

Whatever the party does later, even if it does raise the taxes or cut the taxes, they can still insist that they were not lying.

> We had no **plans** at the time, but now we can see it is necessary.

Nobody can prove them false, but most people can see perfectly well that the government is being disingenuous.  The statement was  true.  There was nothing on paper showing the detailed steps and amounts:  nothing you could call a **plan**.

But this kind of behaviour is not *intellectually dishonest*.  Indeed there is nothing *intellectual* about it.  There is a reasonable stab at an explanation of this expression.

> Harvard ethicist Louis M. Guenin describes the "kernel" of intellectual honesty to be "a virtuous disposition to eschew deception when given an incentive for deception". Intentionally committed fallacies in debates and reasoning are called intellectual dishonesty.

So both are a kind of dishonesty, where *disingenuousness* is not exactly designed to deceive.  It is rather a withholding of ‘the whole truth’.  One British diplomat used the expression *”economical with the truth”*, leaving everyone to understand that the minister concerned had uttered a deception without actually saying so.  And in so expressing himself, the diplomat was being disingenuous (and very diplomatic!).

So no, the two are not the same.

**BUT**...  If you study the examples cited in the Cambridge English Dictionary, actual usage has tended to blur the difference between the two expressions.  So, regretfully, I have to say that yes, the difference is fading.  It is not wrong to use *disingenuous* where *intellectually dishonest* or just dishonest (I should have said) would be better.  It is a pity.   Disingenuousness is not **actually** trying to deceive.

Comment: Outstanding response, thank you so much. You make an excellent argument for the subtle differences between the terms.

Comment: @ConnorSpangler  it at all:  why not tick it?

Comment: Sorry got sidetracked!

Answer (score 0):

In Categorical Imperative Kant states that 'two methods of concealment, are known, respectively, as suppressio veri and suggestio falsi, and many think them legitimate under certain circumstances: while others say that, if deception is to be practised at all, it is mere formalism to object to any   one mode of efffecting it more than another'.  Disingenuousness is a kind of suppressio veri made possible by playing the role of an ingénu.